# What datatype should I use if my number is 32 digits long and is a natural number?

Tags: java

Actually, I am inputting a number 32 digits 
`long(e.g.,10001001100210031004100510061007)` as a `String` and I have to convert into a datatype to perform an arithmetic operation. I am using java and I can't use `BigInteger` class.

Comment: Why you cannot use BigInteger? What arithmetic operation do you need? (+, -, *, /, ???)

Comment: @kennytm  I'm working on an online site and it doesn't support it.

Comment: @AbhinavKushagra I'm pretty sure that Java implementations *have to* support BigInteger. Are you sure it's not simply that you aren't allowed to import it, and so have to use `java.math.BigInteger` explicitly instead?

Comment: @CKing It's not a duplicate as I have stated there that I can't use 'BigInteger' class.

Comment: @AbhinavKushagra Why can't you use `BigInteger` class? Just for fun? Even then, did you search the site for an answer before posting the question? How did the existing questions not answer your question?

Comment: @CKing see above: the platform s/he uses does not support it

Comment: @Izruo Fair enough but we do have answers to that question already I suppose on the site? See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318068/how-to-handle-very-large-numbers-in-java-without-using-java-math-biginteger) for example? It would have been faster to search the site than to type that question IMO.

Comment: I tried to use BigInteger class but it is giving me error on that site. @CKing

Comment: @AbhinavKushagra Did you search *Stack Overflow* before posting a question. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318068/how-to-handle-very-large-numbers-in-java-without-using-java-math-biginteger).

Comment: @Cking They all have used BigIntger somewhere either directly or indirectly.

Comment: @AbhinavKushagra the only reason to be using an online site which won't let you use `BigInteger` is because you're supposed to be completing an exercise to implement a basic version of the class yourself; in which case, asking here defeats the point of the exercise. If not, the online site is simply not worth wasting your time on.

Comment: @AbhinavKushagra Did you even go through the link I shared above in my previous comment??

Comment: @CKing Yes, I have checked that link.

Comment: @AbhinavKushagra And why is that not helpful? Do you want someone to copy paste the answer here?

Comment: @AbhinavKushagra Which online site you are working on?

Comment: @CKing Do you want me to create that class on that online site and then create methods to perform arithmetic operations?

Comment: @AbhinavKushagra How else do you propose to solve this problem if you can't use `BigInteger`? If you don't want to create a class, copy paste what it does in a single method. I don't see any other option.

Comment: @CKing neither do I. :(

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `BigInteger` from your `String` like this :

```
String s = "10001001100210031004100510061007";
BigInteger l = new BigInteger(s);
System.out.println(l);
```

**EDIT**

Like @Andy Turner said in comment you can use `BigDecimal` like this :

```
String s = "10001001100210031004100510061007";
BigDecimal l = new BigDecimal(s);
System.out.println(l);
```

Comment: OP statet s/he can't use `BigInteger`. Edit: It seems to be an edit after your answer.

Comment: So, `BigDecimal` then.

Comment: Sorry, I can't use BigInteger class that's the problem.

Comment: but he said in the first "I am restricted to use BigInteger class"

Comment: chech the edit @AbhinavKushagra

Comment: @YCF_L Sorry, my bad.

Comment: @Izruo you can check the first question http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42328331/1 he said "I am restricted to use BigInteger class"

Comment: @YCF_L As I immediately stated in the edit, I saw the edit date of the question is longer in the past than the date of your answer, so I already guessed something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you really cannot use the `BigInteger` class, you will have to create a custom big number class, perhaps using a `List<Integer>` or `int[]` for underlying storage.

There are examples of this sort of thing on SO already, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318068/how-to-handle-very-large-numbers-in-java-without-using-java-math-biginteger), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490086/handling-large-integers-in-java-without-using-biginteger), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33578118/java-adding-large-numbers-without-using-biginteger).

Comment: but I have to perform arithmetic operations as well.

Comment: The answers I linked to provide implementations of `add` and `multiply`, and I guess the others would be done in a similar way.

Comment: @hughjdavey I believe the OP wants you to build the entire library for them.